# Capturing POP3 with Wireshark

Tags: networking, server, local, wireshark, pop3

I am working on the wireshark project for school. And need to analyze POP3 packets over the network. I have tried capturing traffic over the network and have sent the mail from my phone to my pc using gmail. All protocols are enabled in the Wwireshark. But when filtering through the packets there wasn't POP or SMTP or IMAP packets to be shown, but I do not know why. Then I have tried using Thunderbird and hMailServer to capture the traffic, but I can not manage them to work together, since thunderbird doesn't allow me to create mail account from the hMailServer.
What I want to ask is for advice how to capture POP3 over the network, does it need special configuration when capturing for Gmail and Hotmail accounts. Or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background for you to understand the process. Whenever anyone (including yourself) sends mail to your mail address, it's delivered to Gmail server and rests there. You have number of options to access it:

- View mail on server web interface by opening "mail.google.com" in your browser. Browser uses HTTP (actually HTTPS) to get site content as it usually do with other sites. The fact, that site represents server's state doesn't mean "receiving mail" neither it uses POP/IMAP/anything else.
- Download email to your PC via mail client such as Thunderbird. It requires proper configuration to point client at server address/port/protocol/credentials/etc. Protocol used for downloading is the part of configuration, you're free to use POP whenever server supports it.

So all you need is to configure your Thunderbird to download mails from Gmail via desired protocol and enjoy capturing. Instructions for POP mail clients from [Gmail perspective](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en&visit_id=1-636310820268072686-2150515288&rd=3).

Comment: Thank You! Based on the Wireshark question and answer forum, You are right. The second option which is to use thunderbird and correct configurations is exactly what I need to do. I will try to configure it based on provided instructions. If I do no make it. I'll be back...